# What would I want to do this? 9.999999

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4, floating-point, decimal

If I have a decimal such as `9.999999999` what will I want in my ASP.NET MVC 4 Models to allow this type of decimal to be stored **AS IS** in the database? I believe float is the correct answer. But I am checking here before changing my models over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C# [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(v=vs.110).aspx) type has the highest precision but it uses more memory and performs slower than [`float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9(v=vs.110).aspx) types.

The [`float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza(v=vs.110).aspx) type only has 7 digit precision, so will certainly not be suitable for `9.999999999`.

I would go with [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(v=vs.110).aspx) unless performance is critical for your application.

You can find excellent information at: 
[What is the difference between Decimal, Float and Double in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c)

Comment: if float will let me go to 7 then that's fine, I find decimal only goes to 2 decimals.

Comment: `decimal` will go up to 29 significant figures! You should use it if precision is critical for your app. `float` & `double` are less precise and also susceptible to tiny rounding issues, see [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c) for more info.